# Which firebase services require google play services on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a project where we have an Android tablet that cannot have google play services installed on it.  Which features/services of firebase have a dependency on google play services to run?

Specifically I'm looking at real-time database, authentication, firestore, and firebase cloud messaging.

I spoke with a developer advocate that said that real-time database doesn't have that dependency, but I couldn't find any official documentation that states that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Some Firebase products require Google Play Services, while others don't. Information on this is nowadays included in the Firebase documentation, so I recommend checking out [dependencies of Firebase Android SDKs on Google Play services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services) for the latest list.

Comment: Do you think it would ever be possible to get a guarantee that realtime database will support not having google play services installed?  Our devices won't support google play services and am thinking of an example like Amazon Fire tablets.

Comment: What about firebase storage?

Answer (score 1):

You can see it from the documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services

I managed to run my app after migrating to non play services Firebase Auth, while the database and storage continue to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay service can basically installed apps in its sore onto the device, if you cannot use this you would need to make the app as a "progressive web app" instead then. https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Effectively what you can do through a webpage, using firebase hosting/firebaseDB/storage you would want to simply install a `npm i -g firebase-tools` do a `firebase init` in your project folder and configure your firebase settings to use your apps distribution folder for AnglularCLI the public folder would be "`dist`"

Answer (score 0):

with the old versioning, `play-services-base` and `play-services-auth` were required; eg. to use `FirebaseAuth` with a Google account. the documentation only states `firebase-core` (checked that yesterday, because of a similar dependency question). **but** most likely, the "Login with Google" auth-provider might not be available then - and you would have to offer alternate ways to register an account.