# App won't run without google play services, which are not supported by your device Error while using firebase analytics for react native mobile app

Tags: react-native, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I am trying to integrate firebase analytics on react native app, I have completed all the prerequisites and got a successful build running on Honeywell android Device, but when I open the app it gives above error. There are many such duplicate question but nothing works for me as I can't have play store as the target devices are Handheld android devices and not mobile devices. How to integrate firebase analytics without having to install google play service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Answer @JakeSteam
But I could get firebase integration working without google play service error.

**Issue Details:** 
I was using react native firebase 5.x.x, which works fine but will give a pop up message mentioned in question if your device doesn't have google play service.

**Workaround:**
Upgrade react native firebase to version 6.x.x, the community has redeveloped this repo and I am not having issues with it now.

**NOTE:**
Without google play service on your device you can only use few firebase services like analytics, crashlytics etc.

Answer (score 0):

As [a Firebaser said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206761):

> Firebase as a platform requires Google Play Services, even though some Firebase products may be able to work without it.

If you cannot use Google Play Services, you may want to [look into Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4), which does not require it:

> Note: Google Analytics can be used and will work on devices that do not have Google Play Services. In this case you still download and use the Google Play Services SDK and Google Analytics will automatically fall back to local dispatching.